# Why does transition misplace elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, css-animations, slideshow

I'm creating a slideshow esc. component for a project where I want the current article to show in the middle and half of the previous and next articles to show on the sides (check image).
[image: How it should look]

This works fine when everything is static but I want to add some movement to it, I thought adding a `transform: all 0.5s ease` would bee a good solution but when I add it the items gets misplaced and I'm not sure why (check image below). The element with the red border is supposed to be in the middle of the page[image: Misplaced elements with transition]

Here's the css for the elements:

```css
.slideContainer{
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.previousContainer{
  left: -10%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.currentArticle{
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nextContainer{
  left:110%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `transform: translateX(-50%);` moves everything `50%` to the left

Comment: I removed `translateX(-50%);` but it still has the same problem. When I don't have `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;` everything is positioned perfectly but as soon as I add it everything moves out of position